# Python multiline regex ignore n lines in string

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I have a problem with writing correct regex. Maybe someone can help me?

I have output from two network devices:

**1**

```
VRF NAME1 (VRF Id = 2); default RD 9200:1; default VPNID <not set>
Old CLI format, supports IPv4 only
Flags: 0xC
Interfaces:
Gi1/1/1                 Gi1/1/4
```

**2**

```
VRF NAME2 (VRF Id = 2); default RD 101:2; default VPNID <not set>
Interfaces:
Gi0/0/3                  Gi0/0/4                  Gi0/1/4
```

I need extract interface name from both.

I have regex:

```
 rx = re.compile("""
              VRF\s(.+?)\s\(.*RD\s(.*);.*[\n\r]
              ^.*$[\n\r]
              ^.*$[\n\r]
              ^.*$[\n\r]
              (^.*)
              """,re.MULTILINE|re.VERBOSE)
```

But it is only works for first text, it skips 4 lines and 5 line is exactly what I need. However there are many routers that returning output like 2.
The question is how ignore unknown amount of line and for example find line with Interfaces word and extract next line after "Interfaces:"

Comment: You have the exact code in your question. _"how ignore unknown amount of line and for example find line with Interfaces word and extract next line after "Interfaces:"_ => Split on New line, if the line start with `Interfaces:`, take the next one.

Comment: In regex: `Interfaces:[\n\r\s]+(.+)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT: after providing us with more input, the answer is corrected.*

There are many ways to solve this. Look at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Sp8u4Z/9). The regex

```
(?s)VRF\s([^\s]+)\s.*?(?:RD\s([\d.]+:\d|<not\sset>));.*?Interfaces:(?:\r*\n)\s*(.*?)(?:\r*\n)
```

read in a complete record and captures the Name, RD value and line following `Interfaces`.

Explanation:

```
(?s)                           # single line mode: make "." read anything,
                               # including line breaks
VRF                            # every records start with VRF
\s                             # read " "
([^\s]+)                       # group 1: capture NAME VRF
\s                             # read " "
.*?                            # lazy read anything
(?:                            # start non-capture group
 RD\s                          # read "RD "
(                              # group 2
  [\d.]+:\d                    # number or ip, followed by ":" and a digit
  |                            # OR
  <not\sset>                   # value "<not set>"
)                              # group 2 end
)                              # non-caputure group end
;                              # read ";"
.*?                            # lazy read anything
Interfaces:                    # read "Interfaces:"
(?:\r*\n)                      # read newline
\s*                            # read spaces
(.*?)                          # group 3: read line after "Interfaces:"
(?:\r*\n)                      # read newline
```

Let's look at a test script. I've cut down on the length of the records in the script a bit, but the message still stands.

```
$ cat test.py
import os
import re

pattern = r"(?s)VRF\s([^\s]+)\s.*?(?:RD\s([\d.]+:\d|<not\sset>));.*?Interfaces:(?:\r*\n)\s*(.*?)(?:\r*\n)"

text = '''\
VRF BLA1 (VRF Id = 2); default RD 9200:1; default VPNID <not set>
Old CLI format, supports IPv4 only
Flags: 0xC
Interfaces:
  Gi1/1/1.451              Gi1/1/4.2019
Address family ipv4 unicast (Table ID = 0x2):
  VRF label allocation mode: per-prefix
Address family ipv6 unicast not active
Address family ipv4 multicast not active

VRF BLA2 (VRF Id = 1); default RD <not set>; default VPNID <not set>
New CLI format, supports multiple address-families
Flags: 0x1808
Interfaces:
  Gi0
Address family ipv4 unicast (Table ID = 0x1):
  Flags: 0x0
Address family ipv6 unicast (Table ID = 0x1E000001):
  Flags: 0x0
Address family ipv4 multicast not active\
'''

for rec in text.split( os.linesep + os.linesep):
    m = re.match(pattern, rec)
    if m:
        print("%s\tRD: %s\tInterfaces: %s" % (m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)))
```

which results in:

```
$ python test.py
BLA1    RD: 9200:1  Interfaces: Gi1/1/1.451              Gi1/1/4.2019
BLA2    RD: <not set>   Interfaces: Gi0
```

Comment: Output from real router has more than one VRF, in that case this regex doesn't work properly. I changed regex to match VRF name not ID. Can you look at it https://regex101.com/r/Sp8u4Z/5 ?

Comment: The answer is: you need to read a complete record, starting from VRF until you encouter an empty line or EOF. Like this: https://regex101.com/r/Sp8u4Z/6. I'm going to edit my original anwer using this.

Comment: I see that it works in regex101, however my script is showing error "    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
"

Comment: Does it need to work in one go? I mean, can I split up the records first and do a regex match for each record?

Comment: Doesn't matter how it will be done, in the end I should get VRF name, RD and Interface for each VRF in router.

Comment: Ah. Just noticed that you're looking for the VRF name instead of ID.

Answer (score 1):

> **Positive lookbehind**
>
> (?<=...)
> Ensures that the given pattern will match, ending at the current position in the expression. The pattern must have a fixed width. Does not consume any characters.

From https://regex101.com/

The regex `(?<=Interfaces:\n).+` matches the whole line after each line "Interfaces:"

I tested it on regex101.com and it perfectly worked with both of your examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options, but the one that is closest to your initial attempt  uses optional uncaptured lines:

```
rx = re.compile("""
VRF\s(.+?)\s\(.*RD\s(.*);.*[\n\r]
(?:^.*$[\n\r])?
(?:^.*$[\n\r])?
Interfaces:[\n\r]
(.*)""",re.MULTILINE|re.VERBOSE)
```

However, the first line also looks strange to me and does not compile (missing closing brace), but the `(?:^.*$[\n\r])?` work in your application.